# Enabling or disabling part of TSQL select statement (columns)

Tags: t-sql

Let's say I have a table with five columns. Full select statement would be :

```
Select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 
from tbl
```

But I need this query to be "dynamic", every column must be possible to enable/disable. So, as far as I understand I need five tags (bool let's say).
If i have `tag1=0, tag2=1, tag3=1, tag4=0, tag5 =0` then the select statement should be like this:

```
Select col2, col3 
from tbl
```

If i have `tag1=1, tag2=0, tag3=0, tag4=0, tag5 =0` then the select statement should be like this:

```
Select col1 
from tbl
```

So is there a possibility to do so in TSQL? I intend to create SP and execute it from php.

P.s. I understand that there's a solution to make a bunch of `IF` statements with all possible `tag1...tag5` variations, but this is not very effective when the number of columns (and enable tags) is high.

Comment: Only by going down a dynamic SQL route. Static queries in SQL always return result sets with the same "shape" (the number of columns, and the names and types of each column, are fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create procedure GetTblList
  @Tag1 bit,
  @Tag2 bit,
  @Tag3 bit,
  @Tag4 bit,
  @Tag5 bit
as

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = 'select '

if @Tag1 = 1 set @SQL = @SQL + 'Col1,'
if @Tag2 = 1 set @SQL = @SQL + 'Col2,'
if @Tag3 = 1 set @SQL = @SQL + 'Col3,'
if @Tag4 = 1 set @SQL = @SQL + 'Col4,'
if @Tag5 = 1 set @SQL = @SQL + 'Col5,'
if @SQL = 'select ' set @SQL = @SQL + 'null as NoColumnSelected'

set @SQL = stuff(@SQL, len(@SQL), 1, ' from TbL')
exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

Even tough it is not a recommended practice the only possible way seems to be creating the sql statement as a string and executing it.

If you build the sql statement string in your application layer you can send it to db layer for execution as a single string. This one should be clear.

On the other hand if you want build the sql statement string at DB level (in an SP for example) you can use sp_executesql stored procedure to execute it. Sample:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX); 
SET @sql = 'SELECT col1' 
IF @tag1 = 1 SET @sql = @sql + ', dynamic_col_1'; 
IF @tag2 = 1 SET @sql = @sql + ', dynamic_col_2'; 
IF @tag3 = 1 SET @sql = @sql + ', dynamic_col_3'; 
SET  @sql = @sql + ' FROM myTable' 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Either case you need to send all your tags as parameters or you can aggregate them into a single 5 digit string parameter where each digit represents a flag.